# How to tackle this Inverse Relation homework?

Tags: python, set, addition, relation, inverse

Here is my assignment:

> Write a function **inverse(rel)** that takes a relation rel and returns the inverse relation of the relation rel. The inverse relation InvsetR of the relation R is dened as InvsetR =
>   {(x, y) ∈ S × S |(y, x) ∈ R)}. Example:
>
> > inRelation({(1,1), (1,2), (2,3), (4,2)}) should return
> >
> > {(1,1), (2,1), (3,2), (2,4)}

Here is my code:

```
def inverse(rel):
   m=set()
   for (x,y) in rel: 
      m.add(y,x)
   return m
```

It says that I can add only one element. What can I do?

Comment: You should add a couple `(y, x)` like this: `m.add((y, x))`.

Comment: you need to use `m.add((y,x))`

Comment: `m.add(x,y)` invokes the `add` function with *two* parameters `x` and `y`. You need to pass *one* parameter: the tuple `(x,y)`, so you need to write `m.add((x,y))`.

Comment: Thank you very much! it works now.. but instead of {(1,1), (2,1), (3,2), (2,4)} it returns {(3, 2), (1, 1), (2, 4), (2, 1)}.. why? what should i do?

Comment: @Margarita: in Python, [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) is an unordered collection of unique elements. To have an ordered list, use: `sorted(m)`.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular example, you don't need any custom function of yours, just use the builtins python already provides, a couple of examples:

```
foo = set([(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 2)])
inv_foo1 = map(lambda (a, b): (b, a), foo)
inv_foo2 = {(b, a) for (a, b) in foo}
print(foo)
print(inv_foo1)
print(inv_foo2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If a "relation" is a set of (x, y) couples:

```
>>> relation = {(1,1), (1,2), (2,3), (4,2)}
```

The inverted relation is:

```
>>> inverted = {(y, x) for x, y in relation}
>>> inverted
{(3, 2), (1, 1), (2, 4), (2, 1)}
```

The `inRelation` can be:

```
def inRelation(relation):
    return {(y, x) for x, y in relation}
```

*note: I prefer snake case: `inv_relation`*